# CoffeScript: require not recognized when runninjg from the browser

Tags: coffeescript

I am trying to run this piece of code taken from http://coffeescriptcookbook.com embedding it into an html.

```
net = require 'net'

domain = 'localhost'
port = 9001

connecting = (socket) ->
    console.log "Connecting to real-time server"

connection = net.createConnection port, domain

connection.on 'connect', () ->
    console.log "Opened connection to #{domain}:#{port}"
    connecting connection

connection.on 'data', (data) ->
    console.log "Received: #{data}"

connection.on 'end', (data) ->
    console.log "Connection closed"
```

This code is in file named client.coffe and when i run it with the coffee command: coffee client.coffe it runs fine and connects to the server, but when I embbed it in a html file and open it i get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.

My html script tags looks like this:

```
 <script src="http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/extras/coffee-script.js"
         type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" ></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"
         type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="{% get_static_prefix %}functions.js"
         type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="{% get_static_prefix %}jquery.dajax.core.js"
         type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script src="{% get_static_prefix %}client.coffee"
         type="text/coffeescript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This won't work in the browser.

First issue: Stuff in the browser isn't allowed to connect to other servers or ports than it's coming from for security reasons. Also, you don't get real sockets, just HTTP.

Second issue: `require` is a node.js command you'll only be able to use in node.js (that is, when you run a javascript file with the `node` command or a coffeescript file with the `coffee` command). The `net` module belongs to node.js and will never work this way in the browser.

If you want to talk to the server in realtime from inside the browser, I recommend the [`socket.io`](http://socket.io/) module which uses websockets, flashsockets and HTTP (those are usable from within the browser).

Comment: Thanks or the quick answer, I had no idea about both issues since I am new to javascript. I am going to try to use Connect for the server and io sockets. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can use `require` in a browser with wrappers like [node-browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify). However, all problems pointed out by @thejh are correct, so you'll have to rethink your code.

Comment: Yes, it seems like my approach was completely wrong. Right now I am looking at the book called "CoffeeScript: accelerated javascript developmnt" which has a nice example of io sockts usage in a web browser. Thanks for your answer.